# Как с помощью c++ поменять целостность процесса в Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Как менять целостность процесса в Windows на c++? Как происходит смена уровня целостности? Я могу поменять уровень целостности только с высокого на низкий? И как происходит смена уровня целостности у процесса? (Для этого нужно перезапустить процесс?)

Comment: О какой целостности идёт речь? Где вы хотите её менять?

Comment: @PRODIGY Integrity Level, в ос Windows (нужно для разработки менеджера процессов)